# JMenuitem - click - action - Java

Tags: java, swing, action, jmenu

I have written code to perform click event on JMenuItem but that is not firing when I am debugging. (I know that I am not supposed to ask these questions in this forum but I am new to this forum)

```
public class ClsMenu extends JMenuItem implements ActionListener {

  JTextArea output;
  JScrollPane scrollPane;

  public ClsMenu(String text)
  {
    super(text);
    addActionListener(this);
  }

  public JMenuBar createMenu()
  {
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menuFood,menuDrinks,menuParty;
    JMenuItem foodItem;


    menuBar=new JMenuBar();


    menuFood=new JMenu("Food");
    foodItem=new JMenuItem("Pizza");
    menuFood.add(foodItem);
    menuBar.add(menuFood);
    return menuBar;
  }
  public void createGUIandShow()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Restuarant");
    frame.setJMenuBar(createMenu());
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("item clicked"+e.getActionCommand());
  }
}
```

In this call, I have created an object

```
public class ClsMenuDisp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ClsMenu menu=new ClsMenu("testitem");
    menu.createGUIandShow();
  }
}
```

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Note that all concreate JSomething are meant for _using_ (vs. extending). Or the other way round: if you see yourself extending them, there's a high probability that you do something wrong ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your `ActionListener` to the menu items you are adding the the `JMenu`. What you are doing is make a menu item that has a action listener. Then using a instance method of that menu item to create a completely unrelated `JMenuBar`/`JMenu`/`JMenuItem` that is then attached to the `JFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ClsMenu` class implements `ActionListener`, but it is not by implementing such an interface that you will automatically receive events.

You should add your `ActionListener` to the object you are interested in, so that that object knows it should warn the listener at the appropriate time. In your case, you are interested in the menu, so you should add your listener to it.

Some reference links:

1. The Swing tutorial [about menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)
2. The [Observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which is what you are using when adding listeners
3. [How to write an `ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) tutorial

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing some code that may be useful for you to see as example: link [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-cash/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/simplecash/ui/desktop/main/SimpleCashDialog.java?r=17#28).

There's also a good tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), which is where I based my code on.